# starting an activity from onCreate or onStart

Tags: android

I have an activity that is themed as Theme.Dialog.  I want to have this activity started off the main activity during the latter's onCreate or onStart (depending on some conditions that are checked first).  My problem is that when the "dialog" activity is started this way it doesn't display.  I get a blank activity.

**Manifest snippet:**

```
 <activity android:name="CredentialsDialog"
        android:label="Credentials"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> 
 </activity>
```

**Dialog layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="25dp"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:hint="Your username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:hint="Your password"
        android:password="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

**CredentialsDialog snippet:**

```
public class CredentialsDialog extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        setContentView(R.layout.credentials_dialog);
        getWindow().setTitle("This is just a test");
        getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String user = extras.getString("user");
        String pass = extras.getString("pass");

        // get handle on EditText fields
        final EditText textUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        final EditText textPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

        // pre-populate dialog username EditText with username if it exists
        if (user != "") {
            textUser.setText(user);
        }

        // pre-populate dialog password EditText with password if it exists
        if (pass != "") {
            textPass.setText(pass);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity snippet:**

```
(in either onCreate or onStart)
    if (!loginData()) {
        loginDialog();
    } else {    
        bLoggedIn = qrzLogin();
        toggleUi();
    }
(snip...)
    public void loginDialog() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CredentialsDialog.class);
        i.putExtra("user", MainActivity.user);
        i.putExtra("pass", MainActivity.pass);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

In `MainActivity`, if I called `loginDialog()` a second time immediately after the first, the second would work while the first would be a blank activity.  What am I doing wrong? Opinions welcome too. :)

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: why not to use `Dialog` instead of `Activity` with dialog theme for login ??

Comment: What do you call a blank activity ?

Comment: I started out using an AlertDialog but I want to do validation in the EditText as the user types and couldn't find a way to implement that.

Comment: A "blank activity" has the app_name at the top and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to overriding `onCreateDialog` and `onPrepareDialog` allowed me to add a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` fields in my `AlertDialog`.  This was the end goal anyway.  Also, I have to say I like the dialog handling via `onCreateDialog/onPrepareDialog`.  You can teach an old dog new tricks afterall!